# How to rearrange text file output result

Tags: bash, shell, unix, text

I would like to write a unix script that do the following to have the ff result:

textfile1 contains the following text:

```
    keyval1,1
    keyval1,2
    keyval1,3 
    keyval1,4
    keyval2,1
    keyval2,2
    keyval3,1
    keyval4,1
    keyval4,3
    keyval4,4
```

Expected result:

```
    keyval1 (1,2,3,4)
    keyval2 (1,2)
    keyval2 (1)
    keyval4 (1,3,4)
```

Thank you.

I'm new to unix and this is what I have done so far. It's not working yet though :(

```
 #!/bin/ksh  
 f1 = 'cut -d "," -f 1 keyval.txt' 
 f2 = 'cut -d "," -f 2 keyval.txt' 
 while f1 <> f2 
 do 
 echo f1 "("f2")"   
 done   > output.txt
```

Comment: And where are you struck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a breeze using [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    closeBracket = ""
}

{
    if (key != $1)
    {
        key = $1
        printf "%s%s (%s", closeBracket, key, $2
    }
    else
    {
        printf ",%s", $2
    }

    closeBracket = ")\n"
}

END {
    printf "%s", closeBracket
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but it does not seem to work..what is the value of key in the if statement?

Comment: It starts of as the empty string, but after reading in a line it becomes the first field (e.g. keyval1, keyval2). How are you running it and what is the output? Either **(1)** put the code in a file (e.g. `group.awk`), set the execute permission (`chmod +x group.awk`), then run using `./group.awk <file>`, or **(2)** type it all out on the command line: `awk 'BEGIN ... }' <file>`.

Comment: got it there was a missing ! at the #/usr/bin... thanks!!! may I ask what is the use of %s??

Comment: Sorry about the `#!`, my bad. The `%s` is a string format specifier (see [C++ printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/))

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but I had this one laying around, almost:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>)
{
  /(.+),(.?+)\s*/;
  push @{$h{$1}}, $2;
}
print map {"$_ (" . join(',', @{$h{$_}}) . ")\n"} sort keys %h;
```

Not particular beautiful but it get the job done.